# Listening to Events in the calendar from more than one person using EWS API

Tags: c#, api, events, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Simply I would like to receive a notification every time someone added a new appointment or made any changes on what he/she has.

The only way I know how to do it , is by using 
service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications
but the problem here that it only listens to the account that the service is bound to like in this way

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password)
};

service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(new FolderId[]
{
    WellKnownFolderName.Calendar
}, EventType.FreeBusyChanged, EventType.Deleted);
```

I have solved this problem by creating a list of services each service is bounded to different user and the application should listen to each of them.

The problem with this way is that I need to have the password of each account I wont to listen to its events, which is not possible in real world.

so is there any way to deal with that ?

Comment: Did you consider Impersonation?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem, by creating a list of services, all the services are a clone of the main ExchangeService, with the same credentials for the admin account, but they are impersonated to the other accounts.

NOTE: **You need to setup the server so it allows impersonation.**

```
private void ImpersonateUsers(ICollection<string> userSmtps)
        {
            if (userSmtps != null)
                if (userSmtps.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var userSmtp in userSmtps)
                    {
                        if (_services.ContainsKey(userSmtp)) continue;
                        var newService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

                        try
                        {
                            var serviceCred = ((System.Net.NetworkCredential)(((WebCredentials)(_services.First().Value.Credentials)).Credentials));
                            newService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(serviceCred.UserName, serviceCred.Password, serviceCred.Domain);
                            newService.AutodiscoverUrl(serviceCred.UserName + "@" + serviceCred.Domain, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
                            newService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, userSmtp);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        _services.Add(userSmtp, newService);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Where userSmtps is a list of the email addresses I want to impersonate and _services is the dictionary of services where the first member is the main service.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a service instance per user. There is no way to subscribe to other users folder.

But instead of StreamingNotifications you can use Pull and Push-Subscriptions too.
Something like this:

```
List<FolderId> folders = new List<FolderId>();
folders.Add(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar));
PullSubscription subscription = = service.SubscribeToPullNotifications(folders, 1440, watermark, EventType.Created, EventType.Deleted, EventType.Modified, EventType.Moved, EventType.NewMail);
```

Some time later....

```
GetEventsResults currentevents = m_subscription .GetEvents();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am using StreamingNotifications so I get the notification "instantly" when there are some changes